# Why does $\overline{y} = \hat \beta_{0} + \hat \beta_{1} \overline{x}$ in simple linear regression?

Tags: regression, linear-model, expected-value

Today, once again, I observed that the dependent variable was predicted to be its mean when the independent variable was set to its mean in simple linear regression.

1. Let $(\hat{y},\hat{x})$ be vectors and $(\overline{y},\overline{x})$ denote their means. Does the equation in the title hold in general for a simple linear regression of $\hat{y}$ on $\hat{x}$?
2. What are the mathematical reasons for this?

EDIT: The reason I ask is because I read (Willett & Stampfer. Total energy intake: Implications for epidemiologic analyses. Am J Epidemiol 1986;124:17-27) that to adjust intake of a certain nutrient for total caloric intake, one can take the residuals from a simple linear regression with that nutrient as DV and total caloric intake as IV and add the "expected nutrient intake for a person with mean caloric intake" (so the obtained values are not centered at 0 and often negative, which is strange for something that physically should be strictly non-negative).

So the question follows: Why did the authors not instead more simply say one should add the mean nutrient intake?
It seems odd that these two highly distinguished researchers would not be aware of this equivalence.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "in general"?

Comment: I changed the title.  Is that suitable to everyone?

Comment: @Zen What is so strange?  The OP meant the sample means.  The are expected values for the empiricla distribution.  I would not have chosen that notation but I didn't want to go about changing that too.

Comment: The notation in the original title made it look like the question was why $E(Y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 E(X)$ (which is true by definition if the model is correct) or possibly why $E(Y) = \hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_1 E(X)$ (which certainly isn't true) but it seems that the consensus is that this question is asking why $\overline{y} = \hat \beta_{0} + \hat \beta_{1} \overline{x}$ where $\overline{y},\overline{x}$ are the sample means. This seems correct given the text in the question so I've changed the notation to reflect that interpretation. OP, please revert if this is wrong!

Comment: The notation seems more appropriate now. I meant sample means. @whuber: By "in general" I meant whether this always occurs (and if not, under what conditions it does).

Comment: But "always" comprises exactly what scenarios?  *You* need to stipulate the circumstances and assumptions to be made, not your respondents! Otherwise some people will assume you are thinking of $X$ as a random variable and others will assume it is not random; some may assume it could be a vector of values and others that it is just a single (scalar) value; etc.

Comment: @whuber I am sorry, my limited mathematical capability permits me only so much formal stringency. Please let me know if the formulation is more appropriate now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The point $[E(X), E(Y)]$ does always fall on the least squares regression line when fitting $Y=AX+B$.  where by $E(X)$ and $E(Y)$ we mean the sample averages. In your notation it should be $E(Y\vert X=E(X))=E(Y)$. This is an interesting property of the least squares estimate.  Given $Y_i=A X_i + B +e_i$ is the model with $i=1,2,...,n$.

The least squares estimates for A and B are obtained by taking partial derivatives of $\sum e_i^2$ with respect to $A$ and $B$ and setting them equal to zero.  This leads to two equations in two unknowns and one of the equations reduces to $Y_b=A X_b +B$, where $X_b$ and $Y_b$ are the sample means for $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

To answer the new question from the edit:  You do not add the overall mean nutrition intake for every subject because Their total caloric intake is not always at the mean total caloric intake for the individual subject.  All we said with the first result was that if your total caloric intake is at the sample mean then the expected nutricianal intake would be at the sample mean.  But the authors want to adjust each individual based on his own total caloric intake.

Comment: $\hat \beta_0 = \bar y - \hat \beta_1 \bar x$. **QED**. :-)

Comment: @cardinal Yes I mentioned that in my amended answer.  It is a consequence of one of the equations that results from taking the partial derivatives with respect to the slope and intercept parameters.

Comment: I should have ended my comment above with "and setting them equal to zero."

Comment: @Procrastinator I changed the title to properly express what the conditional expectation the OP meant to give. He used the E(X) notation. I didn't want to change that but I did want to point out that they refer to the sample means.

Comment: @Procastinator Please explain what you are trying to say. Given that the rv X equals its sample mean the conditional expectation of Y which is a point on the regression line is the sample mean of the Y$_i$s.  So what are you concerned about?  What do you think is wrong?

Comment: @MichaelChernick I considered writing $X=E(X)$ but it somehow seemed circular to me

Comment: @miura It is not.  X represents a random variable.  E(X) is a number. X=E(X) just says that the random variable is taking on its expected value.  It is the same as conditioning on X=5 expect that E(X) may be some other number such as 0.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Thanks for answering the add-on question. I feel there is a misunderstanding. I gathered  the correction for each individual's total caloric intake was done just by using the residual from the simple linear regression, getting values uncorrelated with total caloric intake, and the (somewhat arbitrary) addition of a "typical" nutrient amount was kind of cosmetic. My astonishment came from the fact that the mean nutrient intake and the expected nutrient intake for a person with mean caloric intake are the same (if I understood the answers here correctly).

Comment: @miura I am not convinced that what the authors did is right.  I am a bit confused about what they are doing.  But I was trying to address your question.  You seemed to be saying that everyone should get the same adjustment.  If that is a misinterpretation I will remove that part of the answer.  Did you have any objection to the first part of my answer?  My asnwer was essentially the same as Zen's which is the one you checked.

Comment: Yes, your second paragraph says essentially the same as Zen's. I'm unsure as to which question deserves more to be accepted. Maybe the "only one answer can possibly get accepted" approach is not the best in such a situation.

Comment: Hi, miura. I was checking and Michael's answer was posted before mine. So, we don't need this "dilema": please, just give your "accept" to his answer.

Comment: A much more important thing: please, don't use the notation of the mathematical expectation $E[X]$ for the arithmetic mean $\bar{x}=(x_1+\dots+x_n)/n$. These are ultra-standard notations with well established meanings. In **simple** linear regression, The $x_i$'s are fixed numbers pre-determined by the experimenter; they are not realizations of a set of random variables. I'm sorry if this sounds pedantic.

Comment: @Zen I was not complaining about the decision on which answer to check.  Answers often come in at nearly the same time and one isn't aware of the other although a notice does pop up if another aswer is completed while in process of giving one.  I just want to be sure that the OP was not downvoting my answer (part I) and with respect to part II I wanted to know if there was a misunderstanding on my part that could be causing downvoting by the OP or anyone else so I can edit part II out if it is not appropriate.

Comment: Hi, Michael. I didn't mean that. I'm sorry if it sounded any other way.

Comment: @Zen Your suggestion was very kind.  I was not being crtical of you at all.  I just wanted to make sure that I was not misunderstood.

Answer (score 9):

Once you have evaluated the estimates $\hat{\beta}_0$ and $\hat{\beta}_1$, if you have the value of a new predictor $x_{n+1}$, the predicted response is $\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1 x_{n+1}$. In OLS regression, we know that $\hat{\beta}_0=\bar{y}-\hat{\beta}_1\,\bar{x}$. Hence, when $x_{n+1}$ is equal to $\bar{x}$, the predicted response is
$$
  \hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1\,\bar{x} = \bar{y}-\hat{\beta_1}\,\bar{x}+\hat{\beta_1}\,\bar{x}=\bar{y} \, .
$$